# JsonNetResult not returning S#arp Nhibernate object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, s#arp-architecture

I am having a problem returning a JsonNetResult for an object when it is a property of another object, however when I fetch the object explicitly it works e.g.

```
JsonNetResult res = new JsonNetResult();  
 res.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;  
 res.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;  
 res.Data = addressRepository.Get(7);  
 return res;
```

returns a valid result however

```
JsonNetResult res = new JsonNetResult();  
res.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;  
res.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;  
res.Data = businessRepository.Get(businessID).Address;  
return res;
```

will return an empty object; as will

```
JsonNetResult res = new JsonNetResult();  
res.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;  
res.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
res.Data =  addressRepository.Get(businessRepository.Get(businessID).Address.Id);  
return res;`
```

even though the address and it's ID is exactly the same in each situation.
Is there something really obvious I'm missing?

Comment: To clarify: Have you looked at this in the debugger and determined that `businessRepository.Get(businessID).Address` returns the correct object you actually want? What does the debugger say is the value of `res.Data` immediately after the assignment?

Comment: Looking at the debugger the objects look exactly the same except the one that doesn't work has a property called 'HibernateLazyInitializer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a lazy-load problem, which happens when trying to hydrate Json objects. Is the address property a string or does it reference another object? Make sure there's no recursive references, though JsonNetResult should deal with that.

Go into your entity's mapping and add this:

```
mapping.References(x => x.Address).Not.LazyLoad();
```

That should take out any lazy load proxies out of the equation.

Comment: awesome it works thanks.
Guess I can't combine lazyloading with Json